# How to make pyinstaller work with rh-python38-python-devel on CentOS 7?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, centos7

I have `rh-python38-python-devel.x86_64.3.8.6-1.el7` and `pyinstaller-4.3` installed and it's still failing with:

```
28267 INFO: Python library not in binary dependencies. Doing additional searching...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/local/bin/pyinstaller", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 114, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 737, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 684, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "cmd.spec", line 7, in <module>
    a = Analysis(['gooddata/cmd/__main__.py'],
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 242, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 476, in assemble
    self._check_python_library(self.binaries)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 581, in _check_python_library
    python_lib = bindepend.get_python_library_path()
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/bindepend.py", line 956, in get_python_library_path
    raise IOError(msg)
OSError: Python library not found: libpython3.8m.so.1.0, libpython3.8mu.so.1.0, libpython3.8m.so, libpython3.8.so.1.0
    This would mean your Python installation doesn't come with proper library files.
    This usually happens by missing development package, or unsuitable build parameters of Python installation.

    * On Debian/Ubuntu, you would need to install Python development packages
      * apt-get install python3-dev
      * apt-get install python-dev
    * If you're building Python by yourself, please rebuild your Python with `--enable-shared` (or, `--enable-framework` on Darwin)
```

Installed python3 packages:

```
> yum list installed | grep python3
rh-python38.x86_64                       2.0-4.el7               @centos-sclo-rh
rh-python38-python.x86_64                3.8.6-1.el7             @centos-sclo-rh
rh-python38-python-devel.x86_64          3.8.6-1.el7             @centos-sclo-rh
rh-python38-python-libs.x86_64           3.8.6-1.el7             @centos-sclo-rh
rh-python38-python-pip.noarch            19.3.1-1.el7            @centos-sclo-rh
rh-python38-python-pip-wheel.noarch      19.3.1-1.el7            @centos-sclo-rh
rh-python38-python-rpm-macros.noarch     3.8.6-1.el7             @centos-sclo-rh
rh-python38-python-setuptools.noarch     41.6.0-7.el7            @centos-sclo-rh
rh-python38-python-setuptools-wheel.noarch
rh-python38-runtime.x86_64               2.0-4.el7               @centos-sclo-rh
```

Pyinstaller installed using pip:

```
> scl enable rh-python38 'pip list installed'
Package                   Version
------------------------- ---------
altgraph                  0.17
awscli                    1.19.53
botocore                  1.20.53
certifi                   2020.12.5
cffi                      1.14.5
chardet                   4.0.0
colorama                  0.4.3
cryptography              3.4.7
docutils                  0.15.2
greenlet                  1.0.0
idna                      2.10
importlib-metadata        4.0.0
JayDeBeApi                1.2.3
jeepney                   0.6.0
jmespath                  0.10.0
joblib                    1.0.1
JPype1                    1.2.1
keyring                   23.0.1
numpy                     1.20.2
pandas                    1.2.4
pip                       21.0.1
pyasn1                    0.4.8
pycparser                 2.20
pyinstaller               4.3
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib 2021.1
python-dateutil           2.8.1
pytz                      2021.1
PyYAML                    5.4.1
requests                  2.25.1
rsa                       4.7.2
s3transfer                0.3.7
scikit-learn              0.24.1
scipy                     1.6.2
SecretStorage             3.3.1
setuptools                56.0.0
six                       1.15.0
SQLAlchemy                1.4.7
tabulate                  0.8.9
threadpoolctl             2.1.0
urllib3                   1.26.4
zipp                      3.4.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found a hackish workaround:

```
ln -s /opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/lib64/libpython3.8.so /opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/lib64/libpython3.8m.so
```

So it looks like it's not counting with this change: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/12931